How to use zerostep ai function with the Cucumber.js BDD framework
We're trying to integrate the Zerostep AI function into our automation testing framework. We are using the following technologies in our framework: Playwright, JavaScript, Cucumber.js, and Zerostep AI. We are integrating the Zerostep ai function to automate steps like navigating to a URL, filling data in text fields, etc.
The Zerostep ai function takes 2 arguments: {page, test}
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { ai } from "@zerostep/playwright";

test('Verify filling of Form', async ({ page }) => {
    await ai("Navigate to https://www.globalsqa.com/samplepagetest/", {
        page,
        test
    });
    await ai("Type 'statsHarinder' into Name textfield", {
        page,
        test
    });
});

Problem: Now we have a requirement that we have to run our test scripts using cucumber, but when we use the ai function inside our cucumber steps, we are facing an error.
Scenario: Verify User is able to sign in successfully
    Given User Navigates to the application
    And User enters the username
    And User enters the password
    When User clicks on login button
    Then User is presented with the dashboard page

let page; // Declare page object

// Before hook to initialize browser and page
Before(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
});

// After hook to close the browser
After(async () => {
    await page.close();
});

Step Definition file:
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { ai } = require('@zerostep/playwright');

Given('User Navigates to the application', async
function() {
    test('Verify succesfull login', async({
        page
    }) = >{
        const zerostepArgs = {
            page,
            test
        };

        await ai("Navigate to https://www.globalsqa.com/samplepagetest/", {
            page,
            test
        })
    });

Given('User enters the valid email', async function() {
    await ai("Type 'statsHarinderSAgusain@yopmail.com' into Email textfield", {
        page,
        test
    });
});

Given('User enters the valid password', async function() {
    await ai("Type 'Harinder@12345' into Enter Password textfield", {
        page,
        test
    });
});

When('User clicks on login button on vs application', async function() {
    await ai("Click on 'Login' button", {
        page,
        test
    });
});

Then('User is presented on dashboard page', async function() {
    await ai("Validate 'Enroll a new patient' button is visible", {
        page,
        test
    });
});

We have a cucumber.json file for executing and mapping the steps:
{
    "default": {
        "formatOptions": {
            "snippetInterface": "async-await"
        },
        "paths": ["src/test/resources/features/jsdemoweb/*.feature"],
        "require": ["src/test/javascript/jsdemosteps/*.js", "src/test/javascript/hooks/hooks.js"]
    }
}

Using this command to execute our test through cucumber:
npx cucumber-js --config \\src\\test\\javascript\\jsrunner\\cucumber.json

On executing this command, we get an error message:
Before # src\test\javascript\hooks\hooks.js:5

   × Given User Navigates to the application # src\test\javascript\jsdemosteps\loginstep.js:52

       Error: Playwright Test did not expect test() to be called here.
       Most common reasons include:
       - You are calling test() in a configuration file.
       - You are calling test() in a file that is imported by the configuration file.
       - You have two different versions of @playwright/test. This usually happens
         when one of the dependencies in your package.json depends on @playwright/test.
           at TestTypeImpl._currentSuite (D:\IdeaProjects\omronconnectendtoend\node_modules\playwright\lib\common\testType.js:71:13)
           at TestTypeImpl._createTest (D:\IdeaProjects\omronconnectendtoend\node_modules\playwright\lib\common\testType.js:80:24)
           at D:\IdeaProjects\omronconnectendtoend\node_modules\playwright\lib\transform\transform.js:256:12
           at World.<anonymous> (D:\IdeaProjects\omronconnectendtoend\src\test\javascript\jsdemosteps\loginstep.js:54:5)
   √ After # src\test\javascript\hooks\hooks.js:11


Try to execute this ai function with pure Playwright first. (without cucumber)

@I.sh. Thanks for your response .Tried without cucumber and its working fine for me . Command used to execute :npx playwright test

@ggorlen
Thanks for your response . New to stack overflow ,so apologies for formatting. Please find the full error stack trace in above question asked just updated
.Tried to add it in comment but there is a character limit so not able to do it so .

Formatting your error worked fine for me, it's just 6 backticks, no character limit.
